# Including files from folder with foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, include, require

I use following simple code to include all files from common folder.

```
$path=array();
$ds=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$path['root']=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path['common']=$path['root'].$ds."common".$ds;

//Include settings
require $path['common'].$ds."settings.php";

//including common php files
foreach (glob($path['common'].$ds."*.php") as $filename) {
    if($filename!="settings.php")
    require $path['common'].$ds.$filename;
}
```

As you see, at first I use

```
require $path['common'].$ds."settings.php";
```

then including all the rest of files with `foreach` loop.

I wonder, if it is possible to include `setting.php` file first then all other files inside foreach loop, without writing line above?

Comment: Read about php's autoload function.

Comment: @N.B. Why do I need autoload here? Also, autoload for classses, I think.

Comment: You are prepending the path prefix twice. Also using the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is usually pointless, the forward slash works on all systems.

Comment: @mario Pointless? how to use `implode()` function or something similiar withhout DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$files=glob($path['common'].$ds."*.php";
array_unshift($files,$path['common'].$ds."settings.php");
foreach ($files as $filename)
  require_once $filename;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a quirky workaround to "move" the settings script up:

```
$settings = array("$path[common]/settings.php");
$includes = glob("$path[common]/*.php");
$includes = array_merge($settings, array_diff($includes, $settings));

// load them all
foreach ($includes as $i) { include $i; }
```

But that's not so much shorter really.

Comment: @Tural That's only needed due to the `array_diff` trick here. Another alternative would be a `preg_grep` filter and just prepending an entry as Eugen showed.

Comment: (And the next alternative would be renaming your scripts so that they automatically `sort()` in the right order. E.g. make the settings file `!settings.php` or `00settings.php` so that it becomes semantically first. -- I'm using something like that for cron scripts; think `run-parts`.)

Comment: Allthough I agree ```array_map``` to ```include``` would be neat, it won't work as they (include, include_once, require, require_once etc.) are language constructs, and by that not accessible as callback functions. :)