# Including files from folder with foreach loop — not working. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, include, glob

I'm doing approximately like how [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766982/including-files-from-folder-with-foreach-loop) says:

```
$filenames = glob("../webform/components/*.inc");
foreach ($filenames as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
    echo $filename;
}
```

But instead of a bunch of included files, I'm only geting:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in include_once() ...
```

It appears that `$filenames` is empty. Why would that be the case? (I already checked that the folder contains .inc files!)

Comment: What happens if you just try `glob(*.php);` and just echo out the file names?

Comment: After your `glob` call, do `print_r($filenames)` and see what you actually got.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't include that in the code, but I did that and it's empty.

Comment: Use `var_dump($filenames);` and show the output. `glob()` returns a boolean `false` on error, so see if it is erroring or if it's an empty array. I suspect the relative path is wrong.

Comment: Would something like this work? `foreach(glob('../webform/components/*.inc') as $filenames)`

Answer (score 1):

Do a `var_dump($filenames)`. Do you get an empty array, e.g.

```
array(0) {
}
```

If so, the glob worked, but didn't find any files. If you get a boolean false, e.g.

```
bool(false)
```

then the glob failed completely - incorrect path, unreadable directory, etc...

Comment: It's returning bool(false). Why might that be? I believe the path is correct and I don't know why the directory would be unreadable. Is there a way to get a more informative error?

Comment: @beth have you done a `var_dump`, and if so what are the results?

Comment: Yes, a `var_dump` returns `bool(false)`, as my above comment says.

Comment: @beth is your script used in conjunction with a database?

Comment: I'm not sure what this question means exactly, but yes, I'm using Drupal so there's a MySQL database involved.

Comment: @beth Then I suggest you `edit` your question with more relative tags, including `MySQL`, `Drupal` and others you think would be relevant, so that others who have a tags preference, will see it and you'll get more exposure.

Comment: @beth Yep ;-) and if you wish to notify a person in particular (in case you don't know), add a `@` then the person's name, to notify that person. Just saying~ Cheers.

Comment: @beth: Better double check the path, and make sure that ALL the directories in that path are readable. it's not enough to just make components readable, if webforms is locked off. that'd be like an open envelope inside a locked bank vault.

Comment: @MarcB: Done. The permissions are 755 all the way up and down. :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in Drupal from within a module, using a relative path might not work as the `index.php` in `DRUPAL_ROOT` is where your code is run from.

You may want to change it to either (1) or (2) below:

```
// Assuming your webform folder is at sites/all/modules/[MODULE_NAME]/webform
$pattern = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE_NAME') . '/webform/components/*.inc'; // (1)
// Assuming the context is MODULE_NAME.module.
// $pattern = dirname(__FILE__) . '/webform/components/*.inc'; // (2)
$filenames = glob($pattern);
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    include $filename;
    echo $filename;
}
```

If you are doing this from outside a module and not from a script in the root of your Drupal site, use `DRUPAL_ROOT` to set the correct pattern to search for.

(Drupal 7)